# How can I reorder parts of a video file

Tags: video-editing, file-conversion

I have download a mkv movie file which gave me 3 files suffixed .001, .002, and .003.

When i join them together with different tools like winrar, 7zip, hjsplit, concatenated file shows only last 40 min/1.22 hrs of the total length of the movie.

If I play all the (.001, .002, .003) parts with vlc player, I can see that .003 is the first part of the video and .001 is the last part.

Can anyone tell me how can join this parts of movie with correct position or how I can convert .003 file into .001 file.

Comment: Did you try simply renaming the files?

Comment: In general, on superuser we answer questions on the site itself, and if the answer worked, you select it as the right one (and upvote good answers and questions). Keep an eye on the site, and select what worked.

Comment: If you play them in order, in VLC, do you get the whole video in order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line that works on an MKV that had been split.. You can download MKVtoolnix.
The + is important, and I suggest spaces on either side of each +

```
C:\tes>mkvmerge -o qw.mkv qw-001.mkv + qw-002.mkv + qw-003.mkv + qw-004.mkv
```

And you can change `.mkv` to `.001` , `.002` e.t.c. Since you say your extensions have the suffix that increments.

Each of those individual files plays fine in VLC.  And they are ordered in that order.

If the individual ones don't play fine for you, then perhaps there's an error in some of the files you got .   And if they aren't in order for you, then that's strange. Try perhaps putting them in order when you merge them, e.g. like  `file.003 + file.002` e.t.c. if file.003 is first.